# Reverse for 'detail_serial' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have this problem:

> Reverse for 'detail_serial' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z']

html

```
<div class="container" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(auto->fill, 300px);">

    {%for serial in serials %}
      <div class="item">
        {% if serial.poster %}
            <img src="{{ serial.poster.url }}" >class="img-luid"
            alt="">
        {% endif %}
        <p>
            <a href="{% url 'detail_serial' serial.url %}">{{ serial.title }}</a>
        </p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class SerialDetailView(View):
    def get(self, request):
    serials = Serials.objects.all()
    genres = Genre.objects.all()
    return render(request, "serials/single_serial.html", {"serials": serials, "genres": genres})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.Register.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('reg/', views.Reg.as_view(), name='reg'),
    path("serials_list/", views.SerialsView.as_view(), name='serials_list'),
    path("add/", views.AddView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path("single_serial/", views.SerialDetailView.as_view(), name='single_serial'),
    path("<slug:slug>/", views.SingleSerial.as_view(), name='detail_serial'),
    path("actor/<int:id>/", views.ActorView.as_view(), name='actor_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're generating the url with a parameter, you're prefixing the variable with `>`. You don't need to do that.

```html
<a href="{% url 'detail_serial' >serial.url %}">
```

should be

```html
<a href="{% url 'detail_serial' serial.url %}">
```

Are you sure `serial.url` is not empty?